# Binding observable field to dynamically created view

Tags: android, mvvm, observable, android-databinding

I have an interesting question.
In my code I created some RadioButtons dynamically and added it to RadioGroup. But I can't understang how can I add observable boolean value to each of RadioButtons programmatically with using mvvm and databinding but without using xml... 
So, for example, if we would have RadioButtons in xml static we have something like that:

```
<RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/someRadioButton"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:checked="@{viewModel.isChecked}"
       android:text="@string/some_string" />
```

and

```
ObservableBoolean isChecked = new ObservableBoolean(false);
```

in our code.
But how can we add observable field if we don't have buttons in xml but add it in code? Like

```
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this)
radioButton.text = localeLanguage.languageName
RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
radioButton.layoutParams = params
return radioButton
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LiveData showing as below:

```
ViewModel {
  val _radioCheckedLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
  val radioCheckedLiveData: LiveData<Boolean> = _radioCheckedLiveData

  private fun setRadioChecked(checked: Boolean) = _radioCheckedLiveData.value = checked  

  // handle radio check event 
  fun radioChecked(checked: Boolean) {
  if (checked) {
   // do something and change the data source
  }

 fun xxxFun() {
   // if you want to change radioButton check status by code, no need to set RadioButton's status directly
   setRadioChecked(true)
 }
}
```

}

```
Activity {
  val radioButton = RadioButton(context)
  viewModel.radioCheckedLiveData.observe(this) {checked->
     radioButton.checked = checked == true
  }
  radioButton.setOnCheckedListener {checked->
     viewModel.radioChecked(checked)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions.html#java). You get xxxBinding by `xxxBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.xxx, viewGroup, false);`, then `xxxBinding.checked = isCheked`.

Comment: Okay, but it connects only views that we already created in our xml but what if we don't have views in xml and create it dynamically. The answer has been updated to be clearer.

Comment: You can use LiveData.